# The error said: Redundant type argument in new expression use diamond operator instead ...<USCrimeClass> Trying to call a data file to my arraylist

Tags: java, netbeans

```
ArrayList storeList = new ArrayList<USCrimeClass>;
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(inFile);
try ( // Get the object of DataInputStream
           DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream)) {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine;
    // Read File Line By Line
    strLine = br.readLine();// skip first line
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
          // lines
          storeList.add(storeToCrimeObjin(strLine));
    }
    // Close the input stream
```

Comment: What is your question? Since you don't have any type arguments at all, there sure aren't any redundant ones.

Answer (score 0):

There are missing () in `new ArrayList<USCrimeClass>;` it should be:

```
ArrayList storeList = new ArrayList<USCrimeClass>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<USCrimeClass> storeList = new ArrayList<>();
```

The diamond operator `<>` is now in the latter part of the statement.

Apart from that, I'd say @gawi is right.